# How to sort a list of users roles in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

What is the best way to sort a SelectList of users roles like below? I want the role names to appear in alphabetical order.

This my controller code:

```
ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Name", "Name");
```

This is my view code:

```
@foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId)
    {
        input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value" class="checkbox-inline" />
    }
```

**UPDATE - WORKING CODE:**

Controller:

```
var getRoles = await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();
ViewBag.Roles = getRoles.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Roles)
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Name" class="checkbox-inline" />
    <label for="@item.Name" class="control-label">@item.Name</label>
}
```

Comment: Using `SelectList` (which is for use in a dropdownlist) does not make much sense. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738451/post-to-mvc-controller-ienumerable-nested-model-is-null-when-i-dont-select-chec/30745023#30745023) for a better approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amend your controller code to

`ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Name", "Name").OrderBy(x => x.Text);`

If you do this you will then need to change the cast in your view to:

```
@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RoleId)
```

It may be easier to simply change your view code to:

```
@foreach (var item in ((SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId).OrderBy(x => x.Text))
{
    input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value" class="checkbox-inline" />
}
```

as this means no changes to the controller code.

Comment: I tried that but get an error - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem,System.String]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'.

Comment: @MWD See edit. To be honest I'm not sure it's a great use of a SelectList, as this is designed for use with dropdown menus. You could simply pass a `List<String>` to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thanks - ur updated answer works great.. I will also look at using List<String>. Thanks :)